# Smart-table: Search by multiple properties in a column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, smart-table

I've implemented a smart-table in my angular project. At the moment I have a number of persons in an array.

```
$scope.persons = [
    {
        "firstname":"Anders",
        "lastname":"Andersson",
        "city":"Stockholm",
        "country":"Sweden"
    },
    {
        "firstname":"John",
        "lastname":"Smith",
        "city":"Washington DC",
        "country":"USA"
    }
];
```

Which I have bound to my table.

```
<table st-safe-src="persons" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input st-search="firstname" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="lastname" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="city" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="country" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.city}}</td>
            <td>{{person.country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works very smoothly. In each head for every column I can search for the specified property. However, I'd like to redo the table and have two (or perhaps even more, in the future) properties in the same column. In my fairly simple example, I'd like to join my city and country properties into one column as specified below.

```
<table st-safe-src="persons" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input st-search="firstname" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="lastname" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="???" class="form-control" type="search"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{person.city}}, {{person.country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this change, I'd want to be search for both city and country in the third column. What must I do to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea (I bet you can implement this kind of functionality in a couple of other ways).

In a smart-table you can define a safe copy of the data for any manipulations you would want to conduct without modifying the data using the `st-safe-src` attribute. 
in that safe collection, join the city and country strings onto a new property..

`person.location: [person.city, person.country].join(', ');`

or just modify the table data before you pass it to smart-table

then filter by the new 'location' property `st-search="location"`